# Java Stream - Collecting rows of data into less rows with one column grouped into set

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

*I'm new to working with Java streams so I apologize for any misunderstandings.*

I'm looking to use Collect on my stream to return a stream that has a grouped rows that match all elements but one into a singular row, in which that one element is added to a set.

For example, if my stream contains data:

```
[{12, "Apple", "Gala"},
 {12, "Apple", "Fuji"},
 {13, "Orange", "Navel"},
 {13, "Orange", "Valencia"}]
```

After collecting for column 3 it would return stream with data:

```
[{12, "Apple", ["Gala", "Fuji"]},
 {13, "Orange", ["Navel", "Valencia"]}]
```

Is this possible using the stream collect method? Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: When you say "my stream contains data" what exactly do you mean? Is each element an object or an array? I'm assuming array (given your reference to "column 3") but, if so, what's its type? Java array elements must be of a single type but your data contains integers and strings. Does that mean it's `Object[]`? If so, that's not a good idea.

Comment: Is there a one-to-one mapping between the first and second elements or is it possible to have data such as {12, "Apple"}, {12, "Orange"}, {13, "Orange")? If there is a one-to-one mapping then you only need to group on one of the elements. If there's isn't then how should the grouping work?

Comment: @sprinter Sorry, I should've been more clear. The stream is generated from a db query return, that's why I was referencing things as rows, columns, and elements. I thought I mentioned that but didn't, my apologies. Also no, there is no one to one mapping between other elements. But grouping should function just as mentioned, only the cases where column 1 and column 2 match should be combined. Note: it technically wouldn't be possible for those data to exist since it would always have 3 elements per row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to create a fruit class.
Once you've done that, you have three getters

getNumber, getType, getName.

So now you have a List of Fruit named list.

Once you have that, you would do:

```
list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Fruit::getNumber,
        Collectors.groupingBy(Fruit::getName, Collectors.mapping(Fruit::getType, Collectors.toList())))));
```

This will return a HashMap of hashmaps that will look like this:

```
{12={Apple=[Gala]}, 13={Orange=[Navel, Valencia]}}
```

You can replace Fruit::getName with Function.identity() if you want the fruit object to be the key rather than the name.

Comment: That doesn't compile.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, revised.

Comment: This answers the asked question (both supplied answers do, sorry Pons, I flipped a coin) so I selected it as the accepted answer, but it doesn't actually fully address my issue. But that's my own fault for not explaining in enough detail. It does, however, provide insight into my issues so maybe I can try resolving it myself now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [rextester](http://rextester.com/HTTG40310) for this demo

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, Set<String>>> fruitsByIdByType = 
                   fruits.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Fruit::getId, Collectors.groupingBy(Fruit::getName, Collectors.mapping(Fruit::getType, Collectors.toSet()))));
```

Comment: He asked for Map<Integer, Map<String, List<String>>> not Map<Integer, Map<String, List<Fruit>>>  You're values are Fruit, not it's Fruit.type.

Comment: @NickZiebert He didn't actually ask for Map of Maps. Technically, he asked for List of objects, where third field is List.

Comment: @Andreas Technically, he asked for a really crappy data structure and we are left guessing.  But the key is supposed to be by String type ("Gala", "Fuja" etc).

Comment: @NickZiebert thank you for pointing that out. Initially i did the multi-level grouping by and returned the list of pojos. Now i made changes to return only the fruit type values. Please see http://rextester.com/HTTG40310. The only difference between yours and mine is i'm using `Set` to hold the final list of fruit types

Comment: @Pons Oh yeah, hehe.  Look at that.